# Understanding bootstrap grid system classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in using **bootstrap 3**, I have some misunderstanding about using grid system.

I saw some website use only class `col-sm` and other use `col-lg` other used `col-lg` and `col-md` and `col-sm`.

Can I use `col-xs-#` or `col-md-#` or any class for all devices and its go up for all devices or I must use all classes?

How I decide which classes I should use? Help me with some website using bootstrap 3 for different devices. Last thing when I can use `container-fluid` or `container`.

Comment: what is the problem afterall?

Comment: thanks , the problem i'cant decide which class to use to build my grid system for all devices , can i use only class like col-lg for all devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you understand the idea of Bootstrap3 at the first place.

They say: **Bootstrap is "Mobile First"**, this means, the classes of the smaller screen devices are in the higher priority, so they will be used to display first if exist. In case there is no definition for the current screen size, or any definition for a smaller screen, the col will be stacked on each other, in other word, they are all became `col-xs-12`.

Let make it specific:

-You have your `<div class="row"></div>` with several column inside:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="color: white;">
        <div class="row" style="color: white;">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9" style="background: red;">.col-md-6 .col-sm-9</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3" style="background: green;">.col-md-6 .col-sm-3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To understand this, suppose we have 4 different devices opening the website containing the code above:

- Phone (Extra small devices): devices with screen width <768px. These go with class `.col-xs-#`. Bootstrap will look up to see if there is an definition for the screen sizes which is equal or smaller than the current screen size. Here we don't have it, just `.col-sm-#` and `.col-md-#`, which are belong to a bigger screen sizes, and no class of a equal or smaller screen size. In this case, Bootstrap will process the default behavior to ensure that anyway this will be displayed nicely; so it make all the div stacked on each other, or in other words, it makes them all become `.col-xs-12`. Like this:
  [image]
- Tablet (Small devices): devices with screen size >=768px and <992px. These go with class `.col-sm-#`. Now Bootstrap finds there are definition of `.col-md-6`. It just display it as it's defined:
  [image]
- Desktop (Medium Devices): devices with screen size >=992px and <1200px. These go with class `.col-md-#`. This case is the same with the previous case, where Bootstrap find `.col-md-#` and display as it is:
  [image]
- Desktop (Large Devices): devices with screen size >=1200px. These go with class `.col-lg-#`. This case, Bootstrap finds now class like `.col-lg-#`. Now it climbs down the stair to the smaller screen size devices to get the definition of of smaller devices. In this case, `.col-md-#` is the one closest to the `.col-lg-#`, so it will come in place. So we got the same result the same as the case of the medium devices:
  [image]

**After all, we we should remember that smaller screen size classes will have higher priority. You don't have to defined all class for a div but only some that you think they are important and suitable for your purpose of display.**

For your question, the answer is **YES**. You can only define `.col-lg-#` for your website. But when user view it on a phone or tablet or small desktop, all the elements will be stacked on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much you set the highest change, so if I need a col-xs-12 on a phone, but the max ill use is say col-8 on sm->lg ill use col-sm-8.

Your working with media queries here, so they are written as min-width:xxpx so anything above that min-width shall have this rule applied.

Comment: thanks , if i use col-sm- only for all my grid system , it's enough to not use other classes like lg or md or xs ..

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, if want lg, md and sm to all be col-xx-8 you can use col-sm-8 if you want all devices to use col-xx-8 then set col-xs-8